# Copy files from one folder to another based on Date Modified in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have more than 270.000 HTML files in one folder and I want to copy a limited portion of that to another folder. The criterion in the current code is set based on the number of files, but I want to limit it based on the Date Modified.

I tried the following code (with help from an earlier post):

```
Sub CopyXNumberOfFiles(SourceFolder As String, TargetFolder As String, Optional MaxNumFiles As Long = 100)
    
    Dim fso         As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim count       As Long
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim r_date      As Date
    Dim fileModDate
    
    r_date = DateSerial(2018, 1, 1)
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set fileModDate = fso.getfile(filespec)
    
    If Not Right(SourceFolder, 1) = "\" Then SourceFolder = SourceFolder & "\"
    If Not Right(TargetFolder, 1) = "\" Then TargetFolder = TargetFolder & "\"
    
    For Each objFile In fso.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files
        
        If objFile.Path Like "*.html" Then
            
            Path = TargetFolder & objFile.Name
            'fileModDate = Datelastmodified.objFile
            
            If FileDateTime("Path") < r_date Then
                If Len(Dir(Path)) = 0 Then
                    FileCopy objFile.Path, Path
                    count = count + 1
                    If count >= MaxNumFiles Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

How can I adapt the code in such a manner that it only copies the first MaxNumFiles of files under the condition that they are after the r_date.
Given the huge number of files (and the significant number of files that I want to copy to the TargetFolder I hope to prevent too much time loss compared to the current situation. Right now it doesn't seem to look at the date modified at all. It appears to copy the files sorted on filename (oldest files seem to be copied first). It doesn't matter how I sort them in the directory.

EDIT: I tried the above but it gives me Error 53: 'File not found' on this rule:

```
If FileDateTime("Path") < r_date
```

Comment: Did you try modifying the code you posted?

Comment: I tried to use 
 If objFile.Path Like "*.html" Then
   if FileDateTime("Path") < r_date Then
     count=count+1
end if
end if
But that gave an error. I don't know whether to use DateLastModified property, or FileDateTime, or neither

Comment: Would be useful to edit your post with the code you tried.

Comment: Files have properties, including `DateCreated` and `DateLastModified` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object#properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: added some code to sort the matched files by last-modified date

This should do it:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    CopyXNumberOfFiles "C:\Temp", "C:\Temp\vba", 5
End Sub

Sub CopyXNumberOfFiles(SourceFolder As String, TargetFolder As String, _
                                    Optional MaxNumFiles As Long = 100)
    Dim fso         As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim count       As Long
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim r_date      As Date, rs As Object
    
    r_date = DateSerial(2019, 11, 3)
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    EnsureEndingSlash SourceFolder
    EnsureEndingSlash TargetFolder
    
    'create a disconnected recordset for sorting matched files
    Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
    With rs
        .cursorlocation = 3             'adUseClient
        .CursorType = 3                 'adOpenStatic
        .Fields.Append "Path", 200, 300 'adVarChar
        .Fields.Append "LastMod", 7     'adDate
        .Open
    End With
    
    For Each objFile In fso.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files
        If LCase(objFile.Name) Like "*.html" Then      'case-insensitive
            If objFile.DateLastModified > r_date Then
                rs.addnew
                rs("Path") = objFile.Path
                rs("LastMod") = objFile.DateLastModified
            End If 'date cutoff
        End If     'is html
    Next
    
    rs.Sort = "LastMod DESC" 'sort recordset by date (newest first)
    rs.movefirst
    
    'loop over the sorted files
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs("LastMod").Value, rs("Path").Value
        '[perform the copy here....]
        fso.CopyFile rs("Path").Value, TargetFolder
        count = count + 1
        If count >= MaxNumFiles Then Exit Do
        rs.movenext
    Loop
    Debug.Print count & " files copied"
End Sub


Sub EnsureEndingSlash(ByRef pth As String)
    If Right(pth, 1) <> "\" Then pth = pth & "\"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you and it works. However the only issue I would have is that it give the first MaxNumFiles after the cutoffdate (r_date). Is there a way to obtain the first MaxNumFiles of files starting from the most recent one? I know I should have formulated the question more clearly. 
To be clear, my folder is already sorted manually from the most recent file on top (descending). But it seems that vba is always looping from the oldest file (ascending).

Comment: How your folder is sorted has no impact (or no *reliable* impact) on the order in which files are iterated when using `For Each objFile...In...`  If you want to pick the `MaxNumFiles` latest files newer than the cutoff, you'd need to do something like loop all files in the folder, get those that meet the criteria, and then sort them by their modified date descending (maybe on a worksheet?) and copy the top `MaxNumFiles` from that list.

Comment: See the update above.